# Export XML file same structure it was imported

Tags: xml, excel

I want to use excel to open XML file as a table, add some lines to it and export with the same structure.

Problem is, excel completely rebuilds the structure, naming cells like 'cell1, cell2 etc..'. But cells have special name and this info is just lost.

Is there a way I can open XML file in Excel, edit the table by adding some values and then export with the same structure just with modified table.

Oh and I also had to change encoding to 'UTF-8', otherwise Excel wouldn't allow to open it.
Here's full XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-16' standalone='yes' ?>
<units>
  <unit>
    <title>1</title>
    <vocables>
      <vocable>
        <first_meaning>
          <value>da</value>
        </first_meaning>
        <second_meaning>
          <value>yes</value>
        </second_meaning>
      </vocable>
    </vocables>
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <title>dug</title>
    <vocables>
      <vocable>
        <first_meaning>
          <value>net</value>
        </first_meaning>
        <second_meaning>
          <value>no</value>
        </second_meaning>
      </vocable>
    </vocables>
  </unit>
  <unit>
    <title>3</title>
    <vocables>
      <vocable>
        <first_meaning>
          <value>ofc</value>
        </first_meaning>
        <second_meaning>
          <value>of course</value>
        </second_meaning>
      </vocable>
    </vocables>
  </unit>
</units>
```

Comment: The possible answers depends on the XML. So please show at least a part of this XML. Please show at least two list elements of the main XML list. Also please describe how you are importing the XML into Excel.

Comment: @AxelRichter, Edited first post with full code. I tried to import it in 2 ways: simply opening it and importing through 'Data - From other sources - From XML Data Import'. Got the same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of XML can be edited using Excel since it not has any of the [Common issues with importing XML data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmissues).

Open it like described in [Open an XML data file to import its data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-XML-data-6eca3906-d6c9-4f0d-b911-c736da817fa4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#bmopen_an_xml_data_file). It will then look like so:

[image]

Note, I have opened the [Developer tab](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-XML-data-0b21f51b-56d6-48f0-83d9-a89637cd4360?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_showdevelopertab) and selected "Source" from XML ribbon part. While opening a XML schema was created and this will be used for export also. So the structure will be remained.

Now you can simply add new data below the last row.

To export the data in an new XML, use "Export" from the XML ribbon part. A description can be found in [Export XML data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-XML-data-0b21f51b-56d6-48f0-83d9-a89637cd4360?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Simply overwriting the opened XML with the new data is not possible.

What you probably have done, was saving the Excel sheet as an XML file using Excel's Save-As. But this is another kind of XML file and is not related to the XML schema which was created while opening.

Comment: _To export the data in an new XML, use "Export" from the XML ribbon part. A description can be found in Export XML data._ Yes, that was it! I was doing what you described in last sentence. Thank you!